# Package and class names

Tags: packages, document-classes

Here's the smallest question I've ever asked.

Can a package and a class have the same name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the names are distinct by their extension, and `\usepackage` will strictly search for files ending in `.sty`, while `\documentclass` will search for `.cls`.

Comment: If you want a real example: `achemso`

Comment: @JosephWright booooooring, who needs real examples if the theory suffices? :)

Comment: @JosephWright  What happens when you `textdoc`?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides In the case of `achemso`, there is one document covering both, so no real issue

Comment: @YiannisLazarides if you're unsure, use `texdoc -l <package/class>` to get a list of matches, then select the one relevant to you.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides If I'm not mistaken, when several matches are found, a list is proposed to choose the file to open.

Comment: @projetmbc no, by default `texdoc` opens the first match (which is the correct choice most of the time -- note that first match doesn't necessarily mean first found file, but according to some configurations). The list is what the `-l` flag in my previous comment does.

Comment: a smallest question deserved a smallest answer, I'd have cut 23 words from this